# Convert a Java array into a Clojure list or sequence?

Tags: arrays, list, clojure, sequence

How do I convert a Java array into a Clojure sequence data structure, such as a list, or other sequence?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16647261/712526) shows how to do the inverse; The Clojure docs show how to create, mutate, and read arrays; but is there a built-in way to convert them to lists, or some other Clojure-native sequence?

Comment: I just wanted a Clojure-native data type, so that I could work with it more easily with the repl. I see that vector is different, so I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jpaugh is right: Usually a seq is all that you need.  Many clojure collection functions work on many different structures, including seqs.  If you need other collection types, though, you can often use `into`:

```
(def java-array (long-array (range 3)))
(into () java-array) ;=> (2 1 0)
(into [] java-array) ;=> [0 1 2]
```

Note that using `into` to create a list reverses the input order.

One can often use Java arrays as if they were Clojure collections.  I recommend just pretending that an array is a collection in some test code at a REPL, and see what happens.  Usually it works.  For example:

```clj
(nth java-array 1) ;=> 1
```

@jpaugh's answer provides another illustration.

Comment: Props for feeding my ego! ;-p

Answer (score 16):

Yes, there is a way to convert an array to a list! The code `(seq java-array-here)` will convert the array into an `ArraySeq`, which implements `ISeq`, and thus can be treated like any other Clojure [sequence](http://clojure.org/reference/sequences).

Comment: In general this is true, but `pop` won't in general operate on the result of `seq`.  Pop will operate on lists, though.